# Combined usage of String and Varargs in String.format()

Tags: java, variadic-functions, string.format

Wondering if it is possible to combine both a single string and varargs string in a String.format(), like this:

```
String strFormat(String template, String str, String... moreStrs) {    
    return String.format(template, str, moreStrs);
}
```

If I call the above like this:

```
strFormat("%s/%s/%s", "hello", "world", "goodbye");
```

I get java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier 's'

This works:

```
String strFormat(String template, String... moreStrs) {    
    return String.format(template, moreStrs);
}
```

As well as this works:

```
String strFormat(String template, String str1, String str2) {    
    return String.format(template, str1, str2);
}
```

Is it possible to get this to work?

```
String strFormat(String template, String str, String... moreStrs) {    
    return String.format(template, str, moreStrs);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to break out one `str` from the rest of the strings?  Are you attempting to require at least one `str` to be passed?

Comment: No, that's not how the API is defined. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @rgettman and to Jim Garrison: Was just curious to see if it would work and wanted to know the work-around if it did not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
String strFormat(String template, String str, String... moreStrs)
{
    String[] args = new String[moreStrs.length + 1];

    // fill the array 'args'
    System.arraycopy(moreStrs, 0, args, 0, moreStrs.length);
    args[moreStrs.length] = str;

    return String.format(template, args);
}
```